# error: expected ')' before ';' token showing on c program to check if a string is palindrome or not

Tags: c

isn't my assignment,condition and updation in my for loop correct?,its showing the error on that line

```
void main()
{  int i,j,n;
   char a[10];
   printf("\t\tPROGRAM TO CHECK IF A STRING IS PALINDROME OR NOT");
   printf("\n\t\t-----------------------------------------------");
   printf("\nEnter the string: ");
   gets(a);
   n=strlen(a);
   for(i=0;j=n-1;i<=j;i++;j--){
    if(toupper(a[i])!=toupper(a[j])){
        printf("The string is not palindrome");
        break;
    }
   }
   if(i==j){
    printf("\nThe string %s is a palindrome",a);
   }
   getch();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the line `for(i=0;j=n-1;i<=j;i++;j--){` has too may semicolons in it!

Semicolons separate **statements** and `for` takes only three such. To put two (or more) ***expressions*** in the same statement, separate them with commas, as follows: `for(i=0, j=n-1; i<=j; i++, j--){`

Hope this helps.

Comment: yup,that fixed it

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>
 #include<ctype.h>
 int main()
 {
   int i,j,n;
   char a[10];
   printf("\t\tPROGRAM TO CHECK IF A STRING IS PALINDROME OR NOT");
   printf("\n\t\t-----------------------------------------------");
   printf("\nEnter the string: ");
   gets(a);
   puts(a);
   n=strlen(a);
   for(i=0, j=n-1;i<(n-1)/2;i++, j--){
    if(toupper(a[i])!=toupper(a[j])){
        printf("The string is not palindrome");
        break;
    }
   }
   if(i==j || i == j-1){
    printf("The string  is a palindrome\n");
   }
   return 0;

}
```

Comment: your for loop is correct and the program works fine,mine goes to an infinite loop whenever a palindrome string is entered,can u explain why i<=j didnt work?,